# Listview doesn't show items because of emptyview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `listview`. I attached a empty view to it.

When i have this and my `listview` has items, my `listview` shows the items. But when my list is `empty`, my `listview` doesn't show my items.

```
emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_with_hint, (ViewGroup) listview.getParent(),false);
listview.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

When i change `false` into `true` and my `listview` has items, the `items` aren't showed, but when my `listview` is empty, my emptyview shows.

```
emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_with_hint, (ViewGroup) listview.getParent(),true);
listview.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

I request data from the server. I want to set the emptyview after i received the data from the server to evoid that first the emptyview pops up and then the list gets filled up.
When i delete a list-item, the emptyview has to show again.
The emptyview itself is a relative layout.
How can i solve this?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: do you want to toggle between no view (suppose a text or something) and your ListView items?

Comment: kinda, i added more information

Comment: Post your layout which contains the ListView and empty view.

Comment: Why don't you keep the empty view and listview both inside your main layout (where your Listview is at present) and check if ListView has data set visibility of Empty view to Gone and when no data show Empty View and hide ListView

Answer (score 0):

Your empty view needs to be set to `android:visibility="gone"` and be at the same level as your `ListView` in your activity/fragment layout file.

Comment: my empty view is a different layout-file. I have to connect the layoutfile to the listview inside the layout of my activity

Comment: Add your empty view to your activity layout file using the `<include>` tag.  Give it an ID and set its visibility to false in it's parent layout file.  Then set it with `listview.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView))` or whatever ID you give it.  Don't inflate it.  Then let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: thanks, that worked. But i don't actually want to use `<include>`.